Blender won't open properly
I downloaded the latest Blender v4.3.2 and opened it for the first time about a week week ago. It opened properly at first with the Splash window, followed by the Default window to start a new 3D project. I didn't start any new project, closed Blender and didn't get back to it until yesterday to start focusing on learning it. However, now it keeps opening to a blank gray page with the line "Unsaved" in the top left corner.
I didn't start any file that needs to be saved. There is no other command bar or keys to stop this. Other than the "Unsaved" prompt, the page is blank, no way of closing or discarding whatever it is that Blender is saying should be saved.
The only key it responds to is Ctrl S which opens my computer directory to to select a folder to save whatever it is that Blender says needs saving. I'll save whatever it is to Desktop, then delete it, but then when reopening Blender, it starts this process all over again and never offers me a new splash window and default window to start a new project for real. I have a Dell XPS with 32 GB RAM, a GeForce RTX Nvidia 4060 Ti graphics card with 8 GB RAM more than capable of handling my 4K BenQ monitor. Device Manager tells the Nvidia driver and the Intel graphics drivers are both up-to-date. No other app on my computer, including Form Z, Rhino, Corel Painter, Rebelle, Photoshop, and RAM intensive programs are causing any problems, only Blender.
I had done a One Drive backup and wondered if it had duplicated something confusing Blender. So I searched my hard drive and One Drive for any file with .blend as its extension. But nothing is found. The search shows no Blender files. I uninstalled Blender twice and did a complete clean reinstallation including deleting the entire Blender folder in Program Files before a totally new download of Blender. No matter.
As soon as I open the fresh newly installed Blender app, I get the same "Unsaved" screen. No Splash window, no Default window. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this before I decide to trash Blender altogether and use a different 3D program from hereon?
I've searched the web for this problem and a solution.  I've seen similar but not quite the same issue with solutions that don't work in my situation.  Does anyone have a solution?

Please edit the question and share a screenshot of the problem. This sounds like GPU driver issue. Try ignoring Device Manager and updating GPU drivers with the ones you download from Nvidia anyway. You can also try deleting user preferences folder that is in %appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\  (C:\Users\[Your User name]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\ ). Some laptops let you choose which GPU to use, make sure you are using your 4060 instead of the integrated one when running Blender.

Hi Martynas:  I don't think it's a GPU problem because: 1) Blender had no problem opening properly the first time, 2) No other RAM-intensive program I have causes problems.  Only Blender as described in my question 3)  My GPU works fine with my 4K BenQ monitor.  I searched for a Blender preferences folder using the code you suggested, but nothing shows up.

I have a screen capture showing the problem, but I don't see where or how I can attach it to this Stack conversation.  This is the first time I'm using this forum.

It does sound like a GPU problem though. Have you tried updating GPU drivers anyway? Did you make sure the correct GPU is used when running Blender? Those are the things to do in this situation. If that doesn't work, report a bug, try different versions of Blender. Updating GPU drivers is a likely solution though - nothing you have written as far rules it out.

Just to reiterate - yes, other stuff may work with whatever driver version you have and Blender may still have a problem, yes, you may connect another monitor just fine and it can still be a GPU driver issue and yes it may work and then stop working because Windows updates GPU drivers automatically(even when you disable updates :D ) and it happens that this update does not use the correct driver that you will get from Nvidia.

I figured out the problem.  The GPU is fine.  My drivers are fine.  The problem was the cable that came with my refurbished monitor matched the setup diagram for the display ports but is an HDMI cable.  So the new Blender update was feeding off the Intel card but not the NVidia card because the monitor was not connected to the NVidia GPU.  I reconnected with a real Display Port to Display Port cable so all my apps would recognize the BenQ as the primary monitor and look to the NVidia card when processing.  I reinstalled Blender 4.3 -- the latest version.  It opened properly this time.  Solved.

Thanks for all your help, Martynas.  The clue that made me realize the problem was when I went into the NVidia control panel and saw that it was not finding my 4K monitor.  That made me realize all my apps were working off the Intel card which apparently can't handle the new Blender version properly.  By getting a new DP cable and plugging the monitor directly into one of the DP slots linked directly to the NVidia card, the Blender problem cleared up.  HDMI connectors look like DP connectors when you are looking at a diagram.  Monitor status said there was DP input anyway for more confusion.
